# How can I sort my Arraylist alphabetical? (Java)

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections, arraylist

I am kind of new in java and I have not already a big knowledge about coding but maybe you can help me with my problem.
I have a program  which should list all the songs in a alphabetical right order. I want to work with the Collections API. But in my code I don't get it right. Eclipse doesnt give me an error and on the emulator it runs, without to sort it right. Maybe you can show me, transferred to my code what I have to do, to get it running. Sorry for being not as good as you ;) ...But I am young and I want to learn all about coding.
thanks a lot, Vinzenz :)

```
public class SongsManager {

final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getPath() + "/";
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
private String mp3Pattern = ".mp3";
private String mp4Pattern = ".mp4";
private String MP3Pattern = ".MP3";
private String MP4Pattern = ".MP4";
private String m4aPattern = ".m4a";

// Constructor
public SongsManager() {

}

/**
 * Function to read all mp3 files and store the details in
 * ArrayList
 * */
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
    System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
    if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
        File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
        File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
        if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File file : listFiles) {
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    scanDirectory(file);
                } else {
                    addSongToList(file);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    // return songs list array
    return songsList;



}

private void scanDirectory(File directory) {
    if (directory != null) {
        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
        if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
            for (File file : listFiles) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    scanDirectory(file);
                } else {
                    addSongToList(file);

                }

            }
        }
    }
}

private void addSongToList(File song) {
    if (song.getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern) || song.getName().endsWith(mp4Pattern) || song.getName().endsWith(MP4Pattern) || song.getName().endsWith(MP3Pattern) || song.getName().endsWith(m4aPattern)) {
        HashMap<String, String> songMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        songMap.put("songTitle",
                song.getName().substring(0, (song.getName().length() - 4)));
        songMap.put("songPath", song.getPath());

        // Adding each song to SongList
        songsList.add(songMap);
    }
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    List<String> songsList = new LinkedList <String>();
    System.out.println(songsList);
    Collections.sort(songsList);
    System.out.println(songsList);

}



}
```

Comment: Mmh weird déjà vu feeling...

Comment: You're sorting an empty list, and doing it in a `main` method, which Android does not use.

Comment: Copying and pasting code is not a successful way to build an app.  Instead **learn** Java and Android.  The alternative is a lifetime solving problems one by one on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `Collections.sort(songsList)`--once you've populated the list as @Matt points out.

This will work because the items in `songsList` are `String`'s, and `String` implements `Comparable`.

Comment: You might notice that the OP is already trying that... just not _correctly._

Comment: The items in songsList are actually HashMap<String, String>s

Comment: Good call, Matt. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Can you please show me exactly what I have to do in my code now? I dont understand it

Comment: First, Android does not have a `main` method entry point as Matt points out, but that's outside the scope of the question. But you need to construct `songsList`, populate it with multiple calls to `songsList.add(songTitle)`, and then call `Collections.sort(songsList)`. Right now you are sorting an empty list.